# how to insert row in entity 3.5 in detail table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I developed a simple application in Visual Studio 2008 and Entity 3.5. In my database I have a master table and a details table.

In entity 4 or higher we can access master key in details table like this:

```
tabl2.masterkey=.....
```

But in entity 3.5 this not available. How can I insert row in details table?

```
Table2  t2 = new Table2();
T2.TableId1 // this property is unavailable
```

this syntax works in entity 4 or higher but not in entity 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
Table1 t1 = new Table1();
Table2 t2 = new Table2();
t1.add(t2);
```

Talking about T2.TableId1, I think you must know the relation name or the fieldname that make the reference.. check the attributes of t2, and I think, you will found some t1 reference there.

Comment: You probably mean `t1.Table2s.Add(t2);`